Minimizing $\|Ax-b\|$ given that x can only take values 0 or 1
earlier I stumbled upon a question about finding a vector x that minimises $\|Ax-b\|$ where A is a known matrix and b is a known vector. However, I was wondering whether this can be achieved under the constraints that the elements of x can only take the values of 0 or 1.

See also Compressed Sensing

this is binary/boolean/0-1 least squares. Strictly speaking it's NP-hard, but there are lots of approaches to solving it more or less depending on the particulars of your problem.

This is a quadratic unconstrained binary optimization problem.
We want to minimize
$$\min_{x\in \{0,1\}^n} \|Ax-b\|^2=\min_{x\in \{0,1\}^n} x^TA^TAx-2b^TAx+\|b\|^2$$
Since this is an NP hard problem.
Metaheuristic such as simulated annealing and quantum computing techniques such as quantum annealing/ QAOA are commonly used to attempt these questions.
